# getting error when i tap my index.html file of ionic react project, after the project build (by Ionic build command)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-react

I am using Ionic React Project. I need to run my built project by just tapping the index.html file after project build. I built my project by ionic build command and then i tried to run my project by tapping index.html file, getting the given error

> bootstrap:149 GET file:///D:/static/js/7.9625986e.chunk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

screenshot of the errors got and my index.html file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="viewport-fit=cover,width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/icon/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ionic App" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link href="/static/css/4.672a8906.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/main.c51b18ec.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-main.22560124.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/4.1beb7418.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.eec4b2ea.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```